# How to prove that every hereditary C*subalgebra of a non-elementary simple C*algebra has infinite dimension?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

$A$ is said to be elementary if $A$ is isomorphic to some $\mathcal K(\mathscr H)$. A C*-subalgebra $B$ is said to be hereditary if for every $0\leq a\leq b\in B$ we have $a\in B$.

I can see that $A$ is generated by minimal projections which are mutually equivalent, in the sense that if $p,q$ are such minimal projections then there is a $x\in A$ such that $x^*px=q$.

But I do not know what to do next.

Comment: How are you getting $B=\overline{pAp}$? There exist simple $C^*$-algebras with no non-trivial projections.

Comment: @Aweygan We already know $B$ is isomorphic to $M_n$ right? So $B$ has a unit $p$, which is a projection. $\overline{pAp}$ is the hereditary subalgebra generated by $p$ so it is contained in $B$ since $B$ is hereditary. Also, $B$ is generated by its projections which are smaller than $p$. That's how I concluded $B=\overline{pAp}$. Was I wrong?

Comment: @Aweygan There may be simple C\*-algebra with no non-trivial projections, but are they of finite dimension? I'm supposing that $B$ is finite dimensional now.

Comment: I see, I thought you were invoking some result I was unfamiliar with.  As for simple projectionless $C^*$-algebras, $C^*_r\mathbb F_2$ is an example.

Comment: Choose any minimal projection $p$ and view $Ap$ as a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle x, y\rangle$ equal to the unique complex number $\lambda$ such that $x^*y=\lambda p$.  Show that $A$ acts on this Hilbert space by multiplication on the left and that the range of this representation is precisely the compact operators.

Comment: @Ruy Wow thank you alot. It is a great help to me.